# How to retrieve Response Headers data of an API call

Tags: javascript, axios

I am calling an api and its a post request with username and password in it. Now what I want is to get Response Headers content-type. is there a way to get response headers (and store it in local storage for further use) of post request with values .

Comment: how you are invoking the API?

Comment: i am in vue so using Axios

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get('url').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.headers)
});
```

You can get more details like:

```
console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.config);
```

[axios documentation here](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: the api i am calling is post and need username password to be sent for successful working

Comment: axios.post('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/foo/bar', {
  auth: {
    username: 'foo',
    password: 'bar'
  }
});

Comment: i tried something and Api is successful but header has only cache control and content-type, is there a problem in getting all of them

Comment: response headers are coming from backend so you have to set them there

Comment: in network tab i can see other properties but as i am doing console.log for response it has only 2 values, i think this is related to CORS on server side

Comment: If it was a CORS issue I doubt you'd even get a successful response at all... when you just `console.log(response)`, can you find what you're looking for somewhere in there?

Comment: the thing is when i am using like 
```
axios.post(url, params).then(function (response){
  console.log(response);
})
```
i am getting config, headers, request and some more, in that headers has only 2 field which in network tab has 9 values making 7 missing

Answer (score 0):

> **you can view your response details by using developer tools of chrome**

1.visit URL and right click,and then select Inspect

2.then you will see developer tools

3.select network tab and reload the URL

4.right panel includes the URLs that your page requested then select the URL It will show headers in left panel

References: [check this link for more](https://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: i need to store them as well to use future, seeing only won't make a difference

Comment: you didn't ask that in question please update your question

Comment: what is the meaning of retrieval for you bro ?